# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to run Unity game on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

*I'm usually not a Mac/Xcode user, please forgive me for incorrect terms or understandings.*

I have a 2D Unity game which I can successfully build and run on Android and Windows Phone devices/emulators. When building for iOS, I can successfully create the Xcode project, open it and build the app in there. The only change in the iOS-specific player settings I made was to set `SDK Version` to `Simulator SDK`.

However, when trying to run it inside the simulator, the splash screen appears, then Xcode pauses on something that looks like an assemby file with an error message: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)`.

As I had no idea on what to do, I started stripping down my project (in Unity) until I had no more gameObjects but the camera left on the start scene. Also, I removed all other scenes from the build. The only thing that changed was that above error message now seems to appear on another assembly file.

[image: Latest error message]

What could be the issue here? How should I investigate further?

**Update**

This is the stacktrace:
[image: Stack trace]

**Update 2**

I've created a new blank Unity project, and I get the exactly same error there. The problem seems to be related to Unity or my machine, not the app itself.

### Workaround

After days of researching, I still couldn't resolve the issue and finally built for a real devices instead of the simulator. Since I don't own one, I "blindly" submitted the result to the app store, and it got accepted.

For me, that's the proof that the issue is solely related to the combination of Unity and the iOS simulator, i.e. that those two don't work together reliably.

On the other hand, it seems relatively safe to assume that an app will work on iOS if it's been successfully tested on Android, Windows Phone and the default player. Of course, unless iOS-specific features are implemented.

Comment: can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Ok, I added another screenshot. That's the stack trace of Xcode, right?

Comment: Do you have access to the code in the crashing frames, or is that deep within Unity?  I suspect the latter which makes it difficult to offer anything more than general debugging tips (eg: bisect from last good, reduce, log)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not in code I have access to, since the error occurs even before the Unity splash screen. But by now, I'm starting to think that it's solely a simulator issue, since I've had the same hassle on BlackBerry, but on real devices, it works just fine there.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report with Unity about this.  The fact that you've been able to submit without ever testing your app on either the simulator or real device is quite scary.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But on the other hand, the simulator is not officially supported by Unity (from what I've read), but anyway there as a build option. The reason might be they're working on it, but it's not ready for official support.

Answer (score 0):

I only know one reason, that leads to this behaviour (device builds work, but simulator builds won't).

=> This could happen, when using **native iOS code / plugins**

To fix that, you'll have to modify the `<path-to-xcode-project>/Libraries/RegisterMonoModules.cpp` file, cause somehow Unity does not register those classes/methods for the simulator.

Just look for `#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)` defines and shift them to have all your plugins included, also in the simulator. There will be some `move mono_dl_register_symbol()` that you'll need.